# Can't Add simple shapes on Office 2011

Tags: macos, vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying to automate some slide-making using VBA on OSX office 2011.  However, I am unable to add basic shapes.  I thought it might be something the in the complexity of the project, so I boiled it down to the attached test script.  When I run this, I get an 'invalid procedure or method call' error from the last line.    All of this works on a PC, and works when I run it from PowerPoint, but the object model seems to get more complicated when I try to run it from excel.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub test()

Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As Presentation

Dim powerpointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim powerpointPres As Presentation

Set powerpointApp = New PowerPoint.Application

powerpointApp.Visible = msoTrue
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set powerpointPres = powerpointApp.Presentations.Add

Dim sld1 As Slide
Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
Set oLayout = powerpointPres.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1)
Set sld1 = powerpointPres.Slides.addSlide(1, oLayout)

Dim shp1 As SmartArt

Dim shapes1 As Object

Set shp1 = sld1.Shapes.addShape(msoShape10pointStar, 1, 1, 1, 1)



End Sub
```

Comment: The addshape method adds a normal shape, not a smartart object; I'm not able to try this on a Mac at the moment, but I suspect it should work if you Dim shp1 as Shape  instead of as SmartArt

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are in doubt, if it is an object then declare it as an `Object` and if it is a variable then declare it as a `Variant` and then simply add a watch to see the `Type` of that object/variable.

For example

Paste this code in a module and add a `Watch`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Object

    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddShape(msoShape10pointStar, 10, 10, 10, 10)

    Debug.Print shp.Name
End Sub
```

[image]

Another example for objects

[image]

Similarly for a variable

[image]

So in the first case, the object is supposed to be declared as a `Shape` and in the 2nd the objects are supposed to be declared as `CustomLayout`  and `Slide` respectively and finally in 3rd the variable has to be a `Double`

Comment: Or open the object browser, search for the AddShape method and find that it returns a Shape object.  Or Debug.Print TypeName (code_that_returns_some_object_or_value)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: Yup :)